# Where can I put Kotlin code I want to run on app startup when using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have some initialisation kotlin code I want to run when my flutter app starts.

My app already has a MainActivity.kt that exists in app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/my_app/

I then added an onCreate to this activity and added an exception to confirm this code executed....but it did not...

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        throw RuntimeException("blah");
    }
}
```

Where can I put kotlin initialization code that I want to execute on application launch?

Comment: This can be done using the platform channel.  to call native methods from flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You use a different `oncreate` method android first calls this method while loading android app it is lifecycle method.

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

      
        throw RuntimeException("blah");
    }
}
```